# JSON to XSLT : default XML node if JSON element does NOT exist

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I have json structured like:

```json
{
  "Message" :
  {
    "dynamicFields" :
    [ {
      "alias" : "TEST_ALIAS",
      "value" : "VALUE"
      }
      ,
      {
      "alias" : "CAR",
      "value" : "TOYOTA"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have an xslt stylesheet set up like:

```xml
    <xsl:template match="j:map[j:string[@key='value' and text() !='']]">

        <xsl:if test="j:string[@key='alias' and text() != '']">
            
           <ns2:field name="{j:string[@key='alias']}">
                
               <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(j:string[@key='value'])"/>
            
           </ns2:field>
        
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>
```

Which creates elements like:

```
 <ns2:field name="TEST_ALIAS">VALUE</ns2:field>
```

But I can't figure out how to add xml nodes conditionally

For example, if there doesn't exist a JSON element with an alias of `CAR`, add it with a default value

So basically, if the JSON looked like:

```json
{
  "Message" :
  {
    "dynamicFields" :
    [ {
      "alias" : "TEST_ALIAS",
      "value" : "VALUE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The xml would look like:

```xml
 <ns2:field name="TEST_ALIAS">VALUE</ns2:field>
 <ns2:field name="CAR">DEFAULT_CAR_VALUE</ns2:field>
```

the only assumption i can make about the JSON is that there will be elements with both an `alias` key and a `value` key

Comment: It isn't clear what condition your are testing. Do you mean if there was an object in the dynamicFields array that didn't have an `alias` property, or did you mean if there isn't an object at all? Your XSLT is currently data driven, where you produce an `<sn2:field>` element for every one of the JSON objects in the `dynamicFields` array. Can you update the example JSON demonstrating what condition you are trying to handle and use defaults for?

Comment: @MadsHansen updated

Comment: and is the object with `alias: "CAR"` the only one you need to have a default for is missing?

Comment: @MadsHansen yes, there will only be one alias I need to look for. if it exists in the JSON, add it to the XML like the other JSON elements. if it DOES NOT exist in the JSON, add it to the XML with the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing a complete XSLT, I'm taking a bit of a guess, but I think you could add(or modify) the template for the `dynamicFields` property and inside of that add a test to see whether the array contains an object that has an `alias` of "CAR", and if not, add the default `<ns2:field name="CAR"> DEFAULT_CAR_VALUE</ns2:field>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="j:array[@key='dynamicFields']">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:variable name="default-field" select="'CAR'"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(j:map/j:string[@key='alias'] = $default-field)">
        <ns2:field name="{$default-field}">
            <xsl:text>DEFAULT_CAR_VALUE</xsl:text>
        </ns2:field>  
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="j:map[j:string[@key='value' and text() !='']]">
    <xsl:if test="j:string[@key='alias' and text() != '']">
        <ns2:field name="{j:string[@key='alias']}">
            <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(j:string[@key='value'])"/>
        </ns2:field>        
    </xsl:if>    
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: i posted the full stylesheet. it seems that when i try to implement this approach it will add the `CAR` node no matter what, so i'm sure i'm doing something wrong. the only assumption i can make about the JSON is that there will be elements with both an `ALIAS` key and a `VALUE` key. thanks

Comment: wait nvm.. i see what happened. i put your code in the wrong place! awesome, thank you !!!